# Using an AAD User, instead of client secret, with Microsoft Graph API in a headless program

Tags: microsoft-graph, sharepoint-permissions, azure-active-directory

I am developing a small program that creates sites, files, folders, and registers Subscriptions on the root of site. I am using an App in Azure Portal that has Sites.WriteRead.All and Files.WriteRead.All Application permissions. Then in the program we use the Client ID, Tenant ID, and Secret for the App to connect using Graph API. This all works fine but the thing is that the Application permissions are so extensive and give the program the ability to manipulate data for ALL of the users in the tenant. So I am thinking if it is possible to instead create the same permissions but as Delegate permissions and then use a single AAD User which the program uses to log in and do the things the program need. Then the program would only be able to manipulate data that that single user has access to. I realize that this would require the User to accept the permissions in a UI at least once. But if it is only once then maybe it would be acceptable to set it up like that to begin with.

I am not sure if this is even feasible. Does someone have any thoughts about this? Either for or against.

Answer (score 0):

You should use delegated app permissions instead:

[Introduction to permissions and consent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/permissions-consent-overview#types-of-permissions)

The delegated app permissions allow the app to act on behalf of the user, the app can only complete actions that the user has permissions to do so.

You can use AllSites.Read or AllSites.Write, in the delegated context which should achieve your goal. In this context, these permissions mean "All sites that the current user has access to".

Comment: This hardly answers my question. I mention delegate permissions in my question. With this answer I am unsure you understood what I am trying to do.

Comment: I've updated the answer.

Comment: But then the user has to accept the permissions before the users credentials can be used by the app right?

Comment: From the link that you provided it reads: "Delegated access (access on behalf of a user)
In this access scenario, a user has signed into a client application. The client application accesses the resource on behalf of the user. Delegated access requires delegated permissions. Both the client and the user must be authorized separately to make the request. " The fact that the user has to "..sign into a client application." is stopping what I need to achieve. There is no sign in flow in my application. The user clicks buttons and the Graph API app reacts without signing in.

Comment: By sign in, they mean the user has signed in to Azure AD. How can you act on behalf of the user (user's permissions) without them already being authenticated? This isn't a Microsoft specific problem, but a general web development concept. If you are acting without them being signed in at all, then the app is acting from an application only context (app permissions, not delegated app permissions). You can use SSO to authenticate users in your application, Azure AD handles most of it.